# selecting UITextField in custom cell crashes

Tags: ios, uitextfield, custom-cell

I'm trying to create a form like view using custom cells in uitableview. I have 3 custom cells, one with 6 `UITextFields`, one with just one, and one with a UITextView. It displays perfectly, and scrolls up and down with no problems. My problem is that whenever I select anything, either a textField or TextView it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. My break point shows that the textfields are not nil.
Any ideas about what may be causing my crash?

custom cell - properties in .h file - delegates set in custom cell class

```
@interface CandidateInfo1Cell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *firstNameText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *lastNameText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *cityText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *stateText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *emailText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *phoneText;

@end
```

registering my nib:

```
UINib *infoCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:REUSE_INFO_CELLID bundle:[NSBundle bundleForClass:[InfoCell class]]];
[self.listTable registerNib:infoCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:REUSE_INFO_CELLID];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
InfoCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REUSE_INFO_CELLID];
[self configureInfoCell:(InfoCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
```

Comment: Could you paste more from the crash in the output?

Comment: That's another problem, I'm not seeing anything in the output log. Can you suggest how I might get more info about the crash?

Comment: Am I wrong or shouldn't IBOUtlets be weak?

Comment: I originally had them set to weak but I read somewhere on this site that they needed to be strong. Someone else was getting a crash with first responder not resigning properly.

Comment: Outlets should usually be weak, but some need to be strong (it depends on wether the outlet destination is a subview of something). Have you set delegates of the text fields? What is set as the delegate? Has it been destroyed? Turn on zombies...

Comment: I found the problem. I needed to set the delegate to the view controller not the custom cell. Whew!